# Octave keeps executing previous version of my code

Tags: octave

Basically, the problem happens after these steps:

1- I create an algorithm on Octave

2- I save and execute it

3- I change the algorithm

4- I save and execute again

However, for some reason, Octave executes the algorithm as it was in "step 2" instead of the new "step 4" one. The only way to fix it is by closing and re-opening the software every time I edit something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your code saved on the local pc or a network drive? there have been some reports of octave not recognizing that the file has changed because of how some servers update modified dates, so it runs the one already cached instead of refreshing it.

Comment: this is a bug that has been noted before; it doesn't occur in the general case (e.g if you change a variable in a script and rerun the script it will be fine), but there are a few special cases where this has been noted to happen, e.g. when dealing with namespaces, or where octave assumes (intentionally) that functions haven't been updated for the sake of optimisation (e.g. check `help ignore_function_time_stamp`). Can you describe your code structure a bit?

Comment: PS. as the documentation in `ignore_function_time_stamp` suggests, `clear`ing the function before re-running it may solve your problem. Here's also a couple of bugs that may be related: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46281 / https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46282 .  What version of octave are you running btw? (and what OS?)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thanks for pointing to the `ignore_function_time_stamp` function. According to [documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/ignore_function_time_stamp.html) `ignore_function_time_stamp("none")` should make octave recompile all files. But doesn't work in version 6.4.0. After restarting octave, the newest version of my code is execuded. The erroneous behavior seems to appear after I add some of my code folders to path with `add_path(<my folder>)`

Comment: @PaulWeibert I can't comment without an example, but, having said that, many of the related behaviours that were reported as bugs above have now been fixed. It may either be the case that what you described is now fixed in the latest octave (v7.2.0), or you've discovered a bug specifically related to addpath resulting in similar behaviour. I would encourage you to report this in the bugtracker in case it's the latter :)